# is there better way to write this template?

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading Google C++ Testing Framework on `Github`(https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h)

I found the author wrote the following codes,

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
internal::ValueArray3<T1, T2, T3> Values(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3) {
return internal::ValueArray3<T1, T2, T3>(v1, v2, v3);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
internal::ValueArray4<T1, T2, T3, T4> Values(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3, T4 v4) {
return internal::ValueArray4<T1, T2, T3, T4>(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}
..... 
....
...
..
.
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5,
typename T6, typename T7, typename T8, typename T9, typename T10,
typename T11, typename T12, typename T13, typename T14, typename T15,
typename T16, typename T17, typename T18, typename T19, typename T20,
typename T21, typename T22, typename T23, typename T24, typename T25,
typename T26, typename T27, typename T28, typename T29, typename T30,
typename T31, typename T32, typename T33, typename T34, typename T35,
typename T36, typename T37, typename T38, typename T39, typename T40,
typename T41, typename T42, typename T43, typename T44, typename T45,
typename T46, typename T47, typename T48, typename T49, typename T50>
internal::ValueArray50<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13,
T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, T28,
T29, T30, T31, T32, T33, T34, T35, T36, T37, T38, T39, T40, T41, T42, T43,
T44, T45, T46, T47, T48, T49, T50> Values(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3, T4 v4,
T5 v5, T6 v6, T7 v7, T8 v8, T9 v9, T10 v10, T11 v11, T12 v12, T13 v13,
T14 v14, T15 v15, T16 v16, T17 v17, T18 v18, T19 v19, T20 v20, T21 v21,
T22 v22, T23 v23, T24 v24, T25 v25, T26 v26, T27 v27, T28 v28, T29 v29,
T30 v30, T31 v31, T32 v32, T33 v33, T34 v34, T35 v35, T36 v36, T37 v37,
T38 v38, T39 v39, T40 v40, T41 v41, T42 v42, T43 v43, T44 v44, T45 v45,
T46 v46, T47 v47, T48 v48, T49 v49, T50 v50) {
return internal::ValueArray50<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11,
  T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25,
  T26, T27, T28, T29, T30, T31, T32, T33, T34, T35, T36, T37, T38, T39,
  T40, T41, T42, T43, T44, T45, T46, T47, T48, T49, T50>(v1, v2, v3, v4,
  v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, v18, v19,
  v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25, v26, v27, v28, v29, v30, v31, v32, v33,
  v34, v35, v36, v37, v38, v39, v40, v41, v42, v43, v44, v45, v46, v47,
  v48, v49, v50);
 }
```

The author spend hundreds lines of codes to overload the function **Values** in order to take param list from 2 to 50.

My question is "Is there better way to write it"?

Thank you.

--A C++ Noob.

Comment: The "author" seems to be a code generator, not a person.  Read the comments in the file:  `This file was GENERATED by command:   pump.py gtest-param-test.h.pump  DO NOT EDIT BY HAND!!!`.

Comment: You could use variadic templates to express this more systematically, but the code presumably wants to be available to C++98 users.

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointed out it was generated by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This became fairly common in C++98/03.

Starting with C++11, you typically do the same thing with a variadic template.

In fact, at least at first glance, it appears that the entire `ValueArray` is probably pretty close to what C++11 calls a `tuple`.